# PHP Cut String At specific character

Tags: php, character

```
$string = "aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd, eee, fff";
```

I would like to cut string after third , so i would like to get output from string:

```
aaa, bbb, ccc
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14601633/922198

Answer (score 24):

You can use `strpos()` and `substr()` for this. See

- http://php.net/strpos
- http://php.net/substr

  `$string = substr($string, 0, strpos($string, ', ddd'));`

Alternate approach using explode:

```
$arr = explode(',', $string);
$string = implode(',',array_slice($arr, 0, 3);
```

Comment: I wouldn't use the substr/strpos approach that you mentioned (though you could do it in a different way using recursion) because it's relatively inflexible (what if you just want the third , without knowing what comes before and after it), but the implode idea is good.

Comment: Thanks...it worked like a charm..:) using implode i im limiting result on my webpage and its working.

Comment: Oke, good! Please mark the answer, so other users can use it as well.

Comment: strpos(', ddd') is missing the haystack, it should be strpos($string, ', ddd')

Answer (score 9):

```
$x = explode(',', $string);
$result = "$x[0], $x[1], $x[2]";
```

Comment: I think this is the wrong way round, the delimiter is stated first then the string is stated second.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: @fyberoptik - yep - you were right. I've fixed the answer

Answer (score 3):

If you don't know exactly the number chars to count I would suggest an `Implode` `Explode` like this:

```
$string = "aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd, eee, fff";
$arr = explode(',' , $string);
$out = array();
for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++)
{
  $out[] = $arr[$i];
}
$string2 = implode(',', $out);
echo $string2; // output is: aaa, bbb, ccc
```

## Update

here's a [phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/ueq-gty)

Comment: Why `ddd, eee, fff` ? When user wants `aaa, bbb, ccc`.

Comment: @Rikesh - does it make a difference. it's the concept which counts

Answer (score 2):

If it is specific for uptill third string than try,

```
$output = implode(array_slice(explode(",",$string), 0, 3),",");
```

[Demo](http://codepad.org/BRjN6X4y).

Answer (score 2):

```
$string = "aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd, eee, fff";
$arr = explode(", ", $string);
$arr = array_splice($arr, 0, 3);
$string = implode($arr, ", ");

echo $string; // = "aaa, bbb, ccc"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use explode() and implode() PHP functions to get it.