# How to cut a dynamic string from specific character and keep the remaining part in a variable

Tags: php, string

I want a json_decode a string that need a specific format but my string contains some extra text so i want to cut some part of string that is not fixed. I want to cut from specific character that is "{". so how can i cut that text.

I tried these two function substr() and strpos() but these function returning string that i want to remove. From here [PHP Cut String At specific character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14601364/php-cut-string-at-specific-character) .

```
$responseArray = http_post_with_status_code($url, $post_string, "application/json", false, $options);

        $rawResponse = $responseArray['message'];

// This is the expected output of $rawResponse.

 $rawResponse = http code:200 Output:{
  "QueryResponse" : {
    "Header" : {
      "DateTime" : "2019-04-16T07:24:41.718Z",
      "MessageID" : "1111111111111111111111"
    },
  }
}
```

A String without these character (http code:200 Output:)

Comment: Please look into using PHP's JSON APIs.

Comment: Ugly way but it should work : `$response = json_decode(str_replace('http code:200 Output:', '', $rawResponse));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the function you are looking for is [strstr](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.strstr.php).

This should do the trick:

```
strstr($rawResponse, '{');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your goal by using `strpos() & substr()`

Here is the solution:

```php
if (strpos($rawResponse, "{")) {
    $index = strpos($rawResponse, "{");
    echo substr($rawResponse, $index);
} else {
    echo "'{' this character not found!";
}
```